# Enable Textbox oncheck checkbox Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, textbox

Ive been figuring out how to enable an array of textbox when their corresponding checkbox is being checked using javascript...

Here is my code:

```
    $line_util3 = "Select id_code,description from WEBLOAN_SERVER.webloan.dbo.mis_group where pid_code='$list_count' and group_no = '0' and child_node = '1' ";
    $stmt_line_util3=sqlsrv_query($conn, $line_util3);

    if(!$stmt_line_util3) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

    sqlsrv_execute($stmt_line_util3);

    while ($imps_row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_line_util3,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))

    {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='op[]'></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $imps_row1['id_code'] . " - " . $imps_row1['description'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' disabled='disabled' name='txt[]'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    }
```

Thank You very much for the Help

Comment: i added a code .if u have any doubt please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this i hope this will help you. Which uses jQuery.

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name="op[]"]', function () {
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');// true or false
    if (checked) {
        $(this).parents('tr').find('td input[type="text"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $(this).parents('tr').find('td input[type="text"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

here is updated the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e7SZV/8/)**

Comment: do i still need to download the jquery plugin for this? if yes, where could i download it... thank you @bios

Comment: Here [jQuery Downloads](http://jquery.com/download/) I've updated the answer do check.

Answer (score 1):

add an onclick event to call a javascript function to ur checkbox then assign id to the different text box whom u want to disable or enable/disaapear or appear.in the following code i am enabling text box with id 'tpnr' and disabling the other text boxes(id:bs,as)

```
<script type="text/javacript">
function(a){
    document.getElementById("tpnr").style.position = "static";
    document.getElementById("tpnr").style.top = "0px";
    document.getElementById("bs").style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById("bs").style.top = "-10000px";
    document.getElementById("as").style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById("as").style.top = "-10000px";
}
</script>
```

Comment: textbox are dynamically added... i cant assign a id on each textbox i can only use one id for all texboxes but using array

Comment: u can dynamically assign id also like t1,t2,t3 etc inside the while loop.take one more variable and increment it with while loop and correspondingly assign it as id of the particular checkbox.